# How can I type multi line JavaScript code on macOS Terminal's NodeJS console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, terminal

For example, I want to copy and insert multi line code, most that are requiring line breaks

```
var num = 1;
while (num <= 10)
      { console.log(num);
        num += 2; }
```

Instead copying or typing this just executes or sends this

```
var num = 1;
```

How can I do that on NodeJS console via macOS Terminal? Pressing `Return` (Enter) quickly execute the code right away even though I want to just insert a new line. Even `Shift` + `Return`

I want to do this so I'll save time copy and pasting every line, removing line breaks or copying many lines of JS codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `node console` just type `.editor` and enter.

[image]

Comment: I see. I always use the `node` console right away. Thanks for this